# TypeError: this.threadData.pipe is not a function : Angular 6 JASMIN KARMA UNIT Test Cases

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit test cases for angular 6 component, I have below code which is getting error, I almost covered 65% code coverage but this is annoying me and I dont know how to cover pipe in unit test cases.

```
TypeError: this.threadData.pipe is not a function
```

On below line :

```
this.subscriptions.add(
  this.msgDataService.pipe(first()).subscribe((data: any) => {
}
```

I was trying below but don't know if this is a solution or not.
[Angular testing - observable pipe is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607037/angular-testing-observable-pipe-is-not-a-function/52608032)

Thanks

Comment: Have you imported the pipe in your test cases?

Comment: I did not get you, if you can elaborate, I don't think we need to import pipe anywhere in our application.

Comment: Sorry, I understood incorrectly. What's threadData? Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: threadData is an observable.

Comment: Can you post the complete component here?

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if spy on pipe function is missing in unit test.

You will have to create a spy on pipe and return an Observable. Then it will call the pipe function and execute the callback with the returned mock data.

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        let responseData = {};
        this.msgDataServiceSpy = () => ({
            pipe: () => (of({responseData}))    
        });
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [..],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
            declarations: [..],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: msgDataService,
                    useFactory: msgDataServiceSpy
                }
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));
```